# Can I charge my camera while it is taking a video?

Tags: accessories, charger

I have a Canon EOS 1100D and I would like to shoot a long video, of a long concert, for example. Is there a way I can charge it **while it is taking a video** (not just when the battery is in the camera like [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34854/is-there-a-way-to-charge-a-battery-while-still-in-the-camera) asks)?

Comment: You can buy AC adapters that are not batteries that fit into the battery slot. You could try researching them.

Comment: Would this work **while it is taking a video** though?

Comment: It is an alternative to a battery. I believe they are often used in studios. And yes it would.

Comment: Before worrying about battery running out of juice you should probably worry about disk space. [Related](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34811/how-can-i-record-long-videos-on-my-eos-7d)

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34854/21

Comment: @Rowland the great answer to that question had not been written when I asked this and it is linked to already in my question ;)

Comment: @bazite True, but the question is essentially the same thing - charging the battery whilst using the camera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "Canon ACK-E10 AC Adapter Kit" which does not charge your camera but instead allows it to run off of AC power.

But keep in mind that the 1100D/Rebel T3 is only going to allow you to record 17 to 29 minutes of video at a time. You will have to stop and start a new recording every 17 to 29 minutes depending on the settings you use for the video.

Comment: +1 - thanks, just what I was looking for plus extra info :)